# Positioning a member of an interval partition

Tags: discrete-geometry

Let $\ 0<\Lambda_1\le\ldots\le\Lambda_n\ $ be a finite non-decreasing sequence of positive reals, of length $\ n>0.\ $ Let

$$ D:=\sum_{k=1}^n \Lambda_k $$

The question is about the conditions which
allows to shift the interval $\ [0;\Lambda_k)\ $ over arbitrary
$\ x\in[0;D)\ $ by applying a permutation
$\ \pi:\{1\ldots n\}\rightarrow\{1\ldots n\}\ $ to the members
$\ [0;\Lambda_k)\ $ of partition $\ [0;D).\ $ The following simple theorem will provide the picture, then I will reformulate my question in a precise way.

> **Notation:** $\ \mathbb S(n)\ $ is the symmetric group (of all permutations of $\ \{1\cdots n\}),\ $ and the union of the $n$
>   half_closed-half_open intervals (for $k=1\ldots n$)
>
> $$ L(\pi\ k)\ :=\ \left[\sum_{t=1}^{\pi(k)-1}\Lambda_{\pi(t)};
>                           \sum_{t=1}^{\pi(k)}\Lambda_{\pi(t)} \right)$$
>   partitions $\ [0;D)\ $ for every $\ \pi\in\mathbb S(n)$.

**THEOREM 1**
$$ [0;D)\ =\ \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\ n)$$

> ***Remark:*** It is essential to have here intervals for $\ k=n.\ $
>   *In general, the above theorem doesn't hold for* $\ k<n,\ $ i.e. when
>   $\ \Lambda_k\ <\ \max_{t=1\ldots n} \Lambda_t$.

**QUESTION**   What is the necessary and/or sufficient condition for

$$ [0;D)\ =\ \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\ k)$$

This question is still a shorthand for several related questions, be it 
about a single index $k$ or about a group of them.

**Example 1**   If $\ \Lambda_n>\frac D2\ $ then the answer to the *Question* is *NO* for every $ k<n;\ $ **indeed**, for such $k,\ $ no permutation can shift $\ [0;\Lambda_k)\ $ over $\ \frac D2$.

More generally,

if
$\ 2\cdot s<n\ $ and $\ \sum_{t=n-2\cdot s}^{n-s}\Lambda_t\ >\ \frac D2\ $
then the answer to *Question* is *NO* for every $k<n-2\!\cdot\! s$.

---

> **Backround** The above theorem 1 was motivated and serves me as a step (tiny but essential) in my study of Egyptian sums.

Comment: It seems that there are troubles with notation. According to the definition, the right endpoint of $L(\pi\; n)$ is always $D$; so the union of those cannot be $[0;D)$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, thank you for pointing to my nasty typo. I've added the two missing $\pi$ above the $\sum$-s.

Comment: I take it $L(\pi\ k)$ is what some of us would write as $L(\pi,k)$ to indicate that $L$ is a function of the two variables $\pi$ and $k$.

Comment: Bumped by the Community Bot every four months since December 2018.

Answer (score 0):

At the other end of the above statements, if $\ n>1\ $ and
$\ \Lambda_1<\Lambda_2\ $ then the answer is *NO* for $\ k=1:$

**THEOREM 2**   Let $\ n>1.\ $ Then
$$ \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\ 1)\,\ \subseteq
   \,\ [0;\Lambda_1)\,\cup\,[\Lambda_2;D-\Lambda_2)\,\cup\,
    [\Lambda_n-\Lambda_1;D) $$

We see that $\,\ [0;D)\,\ne\,\bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\ 1)\,\ $
when $\ \Lambda_1<\Lambda_2\ $ since the non-empty intervals
$\ [\Lambda_1;\Lambda_2)\ $ and
$\ [D-\Lambda_n-\Lambda_2;\ D-\Lambda_n-\Lambda_1)\ $ are totally
ommitted.

*More generally,*

**THEOREM 3**

$$ \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\ r)\,\ \subseteq
   \,\ \left[0;\sum_{k=1}^s\Lambda_k\right)\ \cup 
   \ [\Lambda_{s+1};\ D-\Lambda_{s+1})\ \cup
   \ \left[D-\sum_{k=1}^s\Lambda_k;\ D\right) $$

where $\ r\le s<n$. Thus, the answer is *NO* for every $\ r\le s\ $ whenever

$$ \sum_{k=1}^s\Lambda_k\ <\ \Lambda_{s+1} $$

*And a positive theorem follows,*

**THEOREM 4**   If $\ \Lambda_n\le\frac D2\ $ and $\ n>1\ $ then the answer is  *YES*  for $\ n-1,\ $ and moreover

$$ \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\,\ n\!-\!1)\,
   \ =\,\ [0;D)\ \quad\Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\quad\ \Lambda_n\,\le\,\frac D2 $$

*Finally, more generally (once again),*

**THEOREM 5** If $\ 1\le s < n,\ $ and
$\ \sum_{k=1}^s\Lambda_k\ge\frac D2\,\ $ then the answer is  *YES* 
for every $\ u=s\ldots n,\ $ i.e.

$$  \bigcup_{\pi\in\mathbb S(n)} L(\pi\,\ u)\,
   \ =\,\ [0;D) $$